# Are there programming languages that directly translate into another?

Tags: language-design

Is there a programming language that doesn't compile, but rather just translates into another language? I apologize if this is a stupid question to ask, but I was just wondering if this would be a literal shortcut in creating a programming language. Wouldn't it be easier (probably not speedy) but still doable?

Comment: There are numerous (free) utilities out there that can do this between various OOP languages.  a quick look -up will point you in their direction. A thorough answer detailing the Pros and Cons of these utilities is beyond my scope at the moment.

Comment: A compiler that "translates into another language" would be a [source-to-source compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source-to-source_compiler).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a programming language that doesn't compile, but rather just translates into another language?

That makes no sense to me. My definition of compilation is "translating from one language (the source language) to another (the target language)".

Usually the source language is something written by humans and the target language is machine code (or asm), but that's not a requirement. In fact, many compilers are structured as multiple layers, each translating to another intermediate language (until the final layer emits code in the target language).

And it's not directly related to a language, but a particular implementation. We can take C, for example: There are C interpreters, C compilers that target assembler code, C compilers that target machine code (of various platforms), [C compilers that target JavaScript, C compilers that target Perl](http://cowlark.com/clue/), etc.

As for simplifying the implementation of a language: Yes, there are various kinds of code reuse that apply.

One way is to separate compiler front-ends (translate from source language to an internal abstract representation) and back-ends (translate from the internal abstract representation to machine code for a particular platform). This way you can keep the front-end and only write a new back-end if you want to support another target platform. You can also keep the back-end and only write a new front-end if you want to add support for another source language.

Another way is to use a full-blown programming language as the intermediate representation. For example, your new compiler might produce C code, which can then be compiled to machine code by any C compiler. The first implementation of C++ [did exactly this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cfront). C has a number of drawbacks as a compiler target language; there have been efforts to create languages better suited for the task (see e.g. [C--](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C--), which is used internally by [GHC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glasgow_Haskell_Compiler) (a Haskell compiler)).

Comment: Does that mean when a new programming language is translated into the target language, the application rewrites the given code and purely translate it into the other? for example a print statement?

new language: `print("hi");`
target language(c++): `cout<< "hi << endl`

Comment: @JasonNümbãr to answer that one needs to know what you mean by "purely".

Answer (score 1):

Today the most commonly translated language is JavaScript. The newer constructs of ECMAScript are translated to the old version to be compatible with older browsers. The translation is done by [Babel](https://babeljs.io/).

There are also other languages like [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/) and [CoffeScript](http://coffeescript.org/) that are translated to JavaScript.

Comment: I never knew JavaScript was translated. You said it is translated to just the older version of ECMAScript. Does that mean the old version is actually compiled?

Comment: No, the older version is interpreted by browser or NodeJS.

Answer (score 0):

[f2c](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F2c) translates Fortran 77 to C code. So it is probably an example for what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

All [general-purpose programming languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General-purpose_programming_language) are [Turing complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness). That means any one of them can be translated into another.

When creating a new programming language, many designers often have their first prototypes translate their new language into one their are familiar with. This makes it easier to check if the translation is correct, that the new language is working correctly, and to share ideas with colleagues since it is machine independent.

When their design becomes stable, they make a front end to an existing compiler to do the compiling. Using an existing compiler has several advantages. Optimization is instantly available. The new language can access existing libraries. Compiling can be targeted to all the existing back ends, making the language available on different architectures.

Comment: I'm pretty sure C is technically not Turing complete.

Comment: @melpomene - really?  The language, not the specific implementations?

Comment: @Prof.Falken Turing completeness requires infinite memory (an infinite tape). In C, all objects must be addressable and the size of a pointer is fixed. Therefore any given C program can only use a finite number of objects.

Comment: @melpomene, must a pointer really be of fixed size? Is it so sizeof for instance can work?

Comment: @Prof.Falken Yes, every type has a fixed size which you can query with `sizeof`. In principle different pointer types can have different sizes, but all object pointer types can be converted to `void *` and back without loss of information, so `sizeof (void *)` provides a strong upper bound on the amount of data a C program can work with directly.

Comment: @melpomene, ok thanks I understand what you mean then. Maybe we should have a different name for "Turing complete" which is, in practical terms Turing complete, although not in infitine mathematical sense. Like a machine with... say 4096 bit sized pointers is pretty darn Turing Complete-*ish*...  :-) and for practical purposes any actual computer.

Comment: The definition of an algorithm is that it must stop at some point. Turing Complete requires finite size.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is one technique for creating new languages. The first experiments in what became C++ were translated to C for compilation. Taken from http://wiki.c2.com/?CeeAsAnIntermediateLanguage:

> Examples of using C in this fashion:
>
> CeeFront; the original implementation of C++, translated to C.
>
> Comeau C++ (http://www.comeaucomputing.com/) translates C++ to C. It
>   is the first C++ compiler to provide full core language support for
>   standard C++.
>
> Several Java-to-C translators out there (some translate Java source;
>   others translate JavaByteCode to C)
>
> Many experimental language compilers use C as a backend, rather than
>   emitting assembly language directly.
>
> SqueakSmalltalk's VirtualMachine is written in a subset of Smalltalk
>   which gets translated to C and fed to the C compiler. The
>   VirtualMachine used by Scheme48 is written in a StaticallyTyped
>   SchemeLanguage dialect called PreScheme which is compiled to C. (The
>   PreScheme compiler itself is written in full Scheme.)
>
> Several SchemeImplementations compile to C (e.g. RScheme, Bigloo and
>   Chicken). These Schemes often use the technique described in
>   CheneyOnTheMta to provide support for ProperTailRecursion.

More recently, compilers targeting a subset of JavaScript capable of efficient on-the-fly compilation have been created - [emscripten](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki).

And if you count assembly language as well as high level languages, [WebAssembly](https://webassembly.org/) or other bytecode languages fit.